# An analytic function on $\Bbb{C}$ has infinite radius of convergence about any point

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, formal-power-series

I may be overlooking a small detail, but this question has me stumped. Suppose $f:\Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{C}$ is analytic. Then, by definition of analyticity, for every $z_0\in \Bbb{C}$, there exists a formal power series $S(X)=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_nX^n$ with radius of convergence $\rho_{z_0}>0$ such that for $z\in \Bbb{C}$ with $|z-z_0|<\rho_{z_0}$, we have
\begin{align}
f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n(z-z_0)^n.
\end{align}
I'm trying to show that since $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}$, it is true that for every $z_0$, we have $\rho_{z_0}=\infty$.

I used to think this was a trivial consequence of the definitions, but now it doesn't seem to be so. I would appreciate it if someone could provide a proof (which hopefully doesn't use any complex integration theory, because I haven't gotten to that point yet).

---

Intuitively, this makes sense to me because if we fix $z_0$ as above and suppose that $\rho_{z_0}<\infty$, then we choose a point $z_1$ on the boundary of the disc $|z-z_0|\leq \rho_{z_0}$. Since $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}$, we can find another formal series $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}b_n X^n$ with radius of convergence $\rho_{z_1}>0$ such that for $|z-z_1|<\rho_{z_1}$, we have
\begin{align}
f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}b_n(z-z_1)^n
\end{align}
Now, there will be some points of overlap in the discs $\Delta_{\rho_{z_0}}(z_0)$ and $\Delta_{\rho_{z_1}}(z_1)$, so maybe this and the principle of uniqueness of analytic continuation somehow provide a contradiction to $\rho_{z_0}$ being finite? I'm not sure how to fill in the details or if this is even the right approach.

Comment: The identity theorem comes to mind.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon could you elaborate?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon but it seems like these are separate issues. That page deals with the question of starting with an analytic function defined in a small region and asking if there exists an analytic extension to a larger domain. But here, the issue is whether the same original formula (the $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}a_n(z-z_0)^n$) is valid in the larger domain; as I wrote in my recent edit, we can find a new series $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}b_n(z-z_1)^n$ which is valid in a different region, but a-priori there is no guarantee that the original series involving $a_n$ converges in the new disc.

Comment: Ok, let me put it this way : let $g(z) = \sum a_nz^n$ (say we are around the point $0$). The power series around $0$ is valid until one hits a pole or singularity of the power series ( This is a corollary of "holomorphic implies analytic"). However, by uniqueness of analytic continuation, the function $f$ is the only way to continue $g$ to the entire complex plane,and this has no poles or singularities. The power series having finite radius contradicts $f$ being a continuation of it.

Comment: I think you need contour integration to do this. The typical proof that holomorphic functions are analytic is given here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions. Observe the second remark, which implies that if the function is entire, i.e. holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$, the radius og convergence is $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to see this is Cauchy's Integral Formula. Write $\gamma_{a,r}$ for the circular contour of radius $r$ around $a$. Then, by Cauchy's Integral Formula, for $w \in B(a,r)$,

$$ f(w) =  \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_{a,r}} \frac{f(z)}{z-w} dz$$

Now note that

$$ \frac{1}{z-w} = \frac{1}{z-a} \frac{1}{1-\frac{z-w}{z-a}} = \frac{1}{z-a} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{z-w}{z-a} \right)^n$$

And we get absolute convergence since $|z-w|/|z-a| < 1$ for $z \in \partial B(a,r)$ (and you can get a uniform bound $ < 1$ using compactness). Since we have absolute convergence, you can change the order of integration (note that $f$ is bounded on a compact set), so we get

$$ f(w) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-w)^n \int_{\gamma_{a,r}} \left( \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} \right) dz$$

Since this is true for any $r > 0$, the radius of convergence must be infinite (by identity theorem you can show this expansion is unique).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there a way of proving this without resorting to integration (i.e just using power series theory alone)?